# window.onresize: firing a function during, and when resizing is complete

Tags: javascript, function, throttling, onresize

I'm new to JavaScript. I am trying to figure out how I would create an onresize function to fire a function during and another one after the user is done resizing the window. Most likely a session timeout will occur.

Any ideas on writing a basic function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onresize = function () {
    // The first function goes here while resizing is happening
    // Then function 2 occurs when window resizing is finished by the user
    }    
</script>
```

Here is the modified version of what I am attempting. The goal is to hide the main capsule div on a page while the page is resizing. Initially when the onresize event is triggered is turns on a div's visibility to be a stand by screen saying "please wait while we process the information".

The Script Exp:

```
var resizeTimeout;
window.onresize = function() {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
         document.getElementById("loading").className = "loading-visible";
         document.getElementById('XXXDIV').style.visibility = 'hidden';
             for ( var h = 1; h < 40; h++)
                 {
                 document.getElementById('DesignXXX' + h ).style.visibility = 'hidden';
                 }
    resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            var hideDiv = function(){document.getElementById("loading").className = "loading-invisible";};
            var oldLoad = window.onload;
            var newLoad = oldLoad ? function(){hideDiv.call(this);oldLoad.call(this);} : hideDiv;
            location.reload(true) = newLoad;
            document.getElementById('XXXDIV').style.visibility = 'visible';
             for ( var h = 1; h < 40; h++)
                 {
                 document.getElementById('DesignXXX' + h ).style.visibility = 'visible';
                 }
    }, 2000); // set for 1/4 second.  May need to be adjusted.
};

</script>
```

Comment: For the resize end handler, consider this plug-in: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the jQuery website there is a comment to resize event:

> Depending on implementation, resize events can be sent continuously as the resizing is in progress (the typical behavior in Internet Explorer and WebKit-based browsers such as Safari and Chrome), or only once at the end of the resize operation (the typical behavior in some other browsers such as Opera).

Comment: @user763349: Try the following code. In IE and Chrome symbols will appear continuously one by one while you will move window's border, but in Opera all several symbols will appear only when you stop resizing.

    `<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onresize = function(){
    document.getElementById('field').value += "A"
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <textarea id='field' cols=70 rows=15>A</textarea>
    </body></html>`

Comment: I ended up using jQuery over the traditional JavaScript method of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
var resizeTimeout;
window.onresize = function() {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
        // handle normal resize
        resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            // handle after finished resize
        }, 250); // set for 1/4 second.  May need to be adjusted.
    };
```

Here's a working example for doubters: http://pastehtml.com/view/b2jabrz48.html

Comment: This simply delays firing the event until 250ms after the event has fired. It is not the same as firing the event _after_ the resizing has taken place.

Comment: Best you can do in web browsers is get close.  See my example.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get that event to fire while resizing is happening, because the event doesn't fire until after resizing has taken place.

[MDN Reference:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onresize)

`**NOTE:**`

`The resize event is fired after the window has been resized.`

Comment: That's not entirely true.  Most browsers will fire it during resize on a regular interval (including Firefox).  I just checked, and I have several JS apps that receive events during resize.

Comment: I love to see your examples. I've just tried it in webkit and firefox and surely enough, it doesn't fire until after you've resized it. http://jsfiddle.net/Dr7dh/

Comment: It's probably jsfiddle that's breaking it: http://pastehtml.com/view/b2ja2yrd4.html

Comment: Nope. Tried it on a local page before trying on jsFiddle. Just tried your example and it did the same thing. Does _not_ fire until _after_ resizing. ***Note*** this is not the same as after releasing your mouse button.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Using Firefox 5, I'm getting multiple events **while** moving my mouse.  I know this has worked since FF3.0, because I've been developing webapps in Dojo for several years that have used it.

Comment: Moving your mouse is resizing the window, hence you are firing the event _after_ you have resized. This is not the same as resizing your window and releasing your mouse button.