# resizing divs with jquery crashes window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I've split my page into three divs and I'm trying to set their dimensions with jquery so that each div is always the same size as the window.

My code is working but after a few consecutive window resizes the div resize begins to lag. This lag gets bigger and bigger the more you resize the window until the browser window appears to crash.

Is there something I can do to make the resize smoother and prevent the crash?

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  sectionSize()

  function sectionSize() {

    var w = []
    var h = []

    var docWidth = $(window).width()
    var docHeight = $(window).height()

    w.push(docWidth);
    h.push(docHeight);

    $(".section").css({
      "height": h,
      "width": w
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
      w.push(docWidth);
      h.push(docHeight);
      sectionSize()
    });
  }

})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.section {
  position: relative;
}
.section p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 45%;
}
#top {
  background-color: blue;
}
#middle {
  background-color: red;
}
#bottom {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <div class="section" id="top">
    <p>next</p>
  </div>

  <div class="section" id="middle">
    <p>next</p>
  </div>

  <div class="section" id="bottom">
    <p>next</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.onresize: firing a function during, and when resizing is complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916404/window-onresize-firing-a-function-during-and-when-resizing-is-complete)

Comment: Before your code changes the size, you need to deregister the resize handler, and then register it after the resize is complete.

Comment: You're creating an embedded function each time, also, you're pushing to a bunch of arrays each time, it looks like it would just leak memory like crazy.

Comment: I suspected that might be the problem Jeff, i'm very much a beginner though and wasn't sure how to get around it. Jeff - thanks for the tip, i'll definitely look into that.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just use CSS `height:100vh;`? Apply that to `.section`

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gsgoruja/1/

Comment: Setting width doesn't even seem necessary since it's a block level element that would default to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your head tag of html.

Use media query in css -

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        .section{
           height : 100px;
           width : 400px;
        }
      }

@media screen and (min-width:450px){
    .section{
       height : //change your css accordingly
       width : //change your css accordingly
    }

}
```